# Why is there a margin above my image even thoughI I've set it to 0px?

Tags: html, css, margin

There seems to be a margin above my image although I haven't set it that way.

I've even tried setting margin-top to 0, but this doesn't fix it.

```css
#header {
  background-image: url(https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/theartonlinegallery-wp/wp-content/uploads/20180627134442/london-cityscape.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 350px;
  background-position-x: 100%;
  background-posititon-y: 75%;
  background-size: 1400px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poiret One";
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Investment Blog</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your spelling at `background-posititon-y`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and look at the box model of each element. The margin comes from the `<h1>`, not from the image.

Comment: You may want to consider using a CSS reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code snippet you posted and look at the computed styles, you'll see that while the `div` does indeed have a `margin-top` of 0, the `h1` block containing "Investment Blog" inside of it does NOT have a `margin-top` of 0. You'll have to do additional styles for the title.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the body tag has default values that you don't see.
Try to add `body { margin:0px; padding:0px; }` to your CSS file and it will set the default padding and margin to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set margin to 0 for both the `body` and the `h1`, like:

```
   body,
   #header h1 {
      margin-top: 0;
   }
```